# Maven proxy of WSO2 packages

Tags: maven, wso2, nexus

I'd like to proxy WSO2 packages via a Nexus. But I can't find the correct URL to proxy :

- http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/?
- http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/?

Both those URLs contains not only WSO2 packages, but also (quite) the entire maven central repository...

Consequently, if I add one of those URLs to proxy in my Nexus, I'll have a lot of duplicates (packages from central repository will be replicated in my central repository proxy AND in the WSO2 repository proxy).

Is there any URL containing **only** WSO2 packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Following repo helped me

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
        <name>WSO2 Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/index.html#view-repositories, it will list all the repositories used at WSO2 (look for the Hosted ones).
You should find the release one : http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/.
Tcho

Comment: Nope...This repository doesn't host the correct packages. For example, carbon-components-4.2.0 is found only in "WSO2 maven2 repository" which is kind of a maven central repository copy!